# Having difficulty with DynamoDB query

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to wrap my head around AWS DynamoDB and having trouble getting records.
If my db item looks like this:

```
{
    "id": string (primary)
    "identifier": string
    "project": string
}
```

I'm trying to get a record using both identifier and project:
Right now I'm doing that like this:

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'MY_TABLE',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':identifier': { S : 'Dave' },
        ':project': { S : 'red_squad' },
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: 'identifier = :identifier and project = :project'
}
docClient
    .query(
        params, 
        (err, data) => console.log(err || data)
    )
```

However it's telling me that it needs the primary key, however I that's not suitable for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use a scan, not a query
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'MY_TABLE',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':identifier': { S : 'Dave' },
        ':project': { S : 'red_squad' },
    },
    FilterExpression: 'identifier = :identifier and project = :project'
}
docClient
    .scan(
        params, 
        (err, data) => console.log(err || data)
    )
```

Comment: One note though: The DocumentClient, does not accept DynamoDB attribute values (**S**, **N**, **BOOL**, ...etc). So, `':identifier': { S : 'Dave' }` should become `':identifier': 'Dave'`.